# How do we know that this function is multivalued?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, branch-cuts, multivalued-functions

So I have an integral $$ \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{1}{2}\left(e^{e^{ix}} + e^{e^{-ix}}\right) \text{ d}x$$

I am told that I am able to substitute $z=e^{ix}$ into this and convert it into a contour integral. This integral would have a pole at $0$, and a branch cut about the negative real number line, and we would make a counterclockwise keyhole contour about the unit circle to solve this.

When I directly look at what Mathematica says as the integral's indefinite antiderivative $$\frac{-i\operatorname{Ei}(e^{ix})+i\operatorname{Ei}(e^{-ix})}{2}+C$$ I can see where some of these come from. $\operatorname{Ei}(z)$ is undefined at $z=0$, which gives us a pole at $0$. $\operatorname{Ei}(z)$ also approaches $0$ as we approach complex infinity, giving us a pole at complex infinity.

Furthermore, despite both $\operatorname{Ei}(x)$ and $e^{ix}$ not being multivalued, for complex $z$, $\operatorname{Ei}(z)$ is indeed multivalued. Since $z=e^{ix}$ will never be $0$, our contour will not hit the pole as well.

However, this raises a few questions. First off, how do we know all of this by just looking at the original integrand $\frac{1}{2}\left(e^{e^{ix}} + e^{e^{-ix}}\right)$? When we are presented with the integral, we don't know it's indefinite antiderivative, so how would we know what its poles are and if it is multivalued or not? For all I know, $e^z$ is always single valued.

Moreover, why is the branch cut along the negative real axis? The poles are 0 and complex infinity. Why is the contour from 0 to negative real infinity instead?

Comment: $\operatorname{Ei}$ does not have a pole at the origin, it has a logarithmic singularity there. It may be defined on the Riemann surface of the logarithm via $$
\operatorname{Ei}(z) = \gamma  + \log z + \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{z^n }}{{n!n}}},
$$ where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant. Btw, $\operatorname{Ei}(z) \to +\infty$ as $z\to +\infty$. What is your definition of $\operatorname{Ei}(z)$?

Comment: @Gary for Ei(Z)^^ https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Ei%28z%29

Comment: Ok, then we are using the same definition and what I said above holds true.

Comment: @Gary Well there would be a branch point at complex infinity, not real infinity.

Comment: Note that $$
z \mapsto \frac{{ - i\operatorname{Ei}(e^{iz} ) + i\operatorname{Ei}(e^{ - iz} )}}{2}
$$ is an entire function.

Comment: @Gary but when we are evaluating the integral we don't know that this is the antiderivative. How do we determine poles and branch points from solely the integrand $\frac{1}{2}\left(e^{e^{ix}} + e^{e^{-ix}}\right)$?

Comment: $$
z \mapsto \frac{1}{2}\left( {e^{e^{iz} }  + e^{e^{ - iz} } } \right)
$$ is entire, i.e., it is analytic on the whole complex plane. Thus, any of its primitives is also entire, i.e., it does not have any kind of singularities.

Comment: If instead you call $z=e^{ix}$ then $$
z \mapsto \frac{1}{2}\left( {e^z  + e^{1/z} } \right)
$$ has an essential singularity at $z=0$. But essential singularities are isolated ones not branch points.

Comment: @Gary how would we determine the branch cut and how the function is somehow multivalued?

Comment: I really do not understand what you are talking about. What branchcut? None of these functions have branch points. Have you received any formal education in basic complex function theory if I may ask?

Comment: @Gary no from my understanding, to evaluate the integral, we would substitute $z=e^{ix}$ and integrate about a unit circle keyhole contour with the "keyhole" about the negative x axis?

Comment: No, you integrate along the unit circle and use the residue theorem: $$
\int_0^{2\pi } {\frac{1}{2}\left( {e^{e^{ix} }  + e^{e^{ - ix} } } \right)dx}  = \int_{\left| z \right| = 1} {\frac{1}{2}\left( {e^z  + e^{1/z} } \right)\frac{{dz}}{{iz}}}  = \pi \frac{1}{{2\pi i}}\int_{\left| z \right| = 1} {\frac{{e^z  + e^{1/z} }}{z}dz}  \\ = \pi \mathop {{\rm Res}}\limits_{z = 0} \left( {\frac{{e^z  + e^{1/z} }}{z}} \right) = \pi  \cdot 2 = 2\pi .
$$

Comment: @Gary ah so there is no branch cut, only a pole at 0 and the contour would just be a unit circle and not a keyhole?

Comment: I told you that you do not have a pole, you have an essential singularity at $z=0$. It is an isolated singularity (as all essentials are) so no need for branchcuts. You just integrate along a closed contour surrounding $z=0$. Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolated_singularity and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem

Comment: I see. thank you.

Comment: For future reference to anyone who is unfortunate enough to stumble upon this question *but* has the insight to click on the more comments button - this question was basically me just not understanding the concept of branch cuts and branch points when I was self studying complex analysis. Ei has no branch cut or branch point, but I was confounded by the mathematica plot, so i had severe misconceptions. :) so if you are confused by what I am even asking in this question just go to another question since this one probably isn't what your own question is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all there is no Multivalued function here so
you are talking about branch point and branch that will
help you in only case of multivalued functions
this is a simple integral

> $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1}{2}\left(e^{e^{\iota\theta}}+e^{e^{-\iota\theta}}\right)d\theta$
> To solve this integral you have to put $e^{\iota\theta}=z $ which will give give you
> a unit circle now you have simple closed contour you can integrate easly
> using Cauchy's residue theorem
> $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1}{2}\left(e^{e^{\iota\theta}}+e^{e^{-\iota\theta}}\right)d\theta=\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{1}{2}\left(e^z +e^{\frac{1}{z}}\right)dz$

$\displaystyle=\frac{1}{2}\oint_{|z|=1}\exp\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)dz=\pi\iota\textbf{Res}_{z=0}\exp\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)=\iota\pi$
You can do this using antiderivative but you then you have to integrate along the line